# Override and reset CSS style: auto or none don't work

Tags: css, width, overriding

I would like to override following CSS styling defined for all tables:

```
table {
        font-size: 12px;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 400px;
        display:inline-table;
    }
```

I have specific table with class called `'other'`.
Finally table decoration should looks like:

```
table.other {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

so i need remove 3 properties: `width`,`min-width` and `display`

I tried to reset with `none` or `auto`, but didn't help, I mean these cases:

```
table.other {
    width: auto;
    min-width: auto;
    display:auto;
}
table.other {
    width: none;
    min-width: none;
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I believe the reason why the first set of properties will not work is because there is no `auto` value for [`display`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display), so that property should be ignored. In that case, `inline-table` will still take effect, and as `width` do not apply to `inline` elements, that set of properties will not do anything.

The second set of properties will simply hide the table, as that's what `display: none` is for.

Try resetting it to `table` instead:

```
table.other {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    display: table;
}
```

**Edit:** [`min-width`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width) defaults to `0`, not `auto`

Comment: strange, I'm looking with firebug - min-width wasn't overriden by auto

Comment: @sergionni Oh yes, I forgot - `min-width` has a default value of `0` - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/min-width

Comment: i've looked again to firebug, there is also problem,that ther're have nested tables, so overriding should be applied to all hierarchy

Comment: @sergionni You can do that by adding `table.other table` to the selector used for the resetting properties

Comment: `width: auto` when all I wanted to override was `width: 100%` -- Thank you

Answer (score 23):

"none" does not do what you assume it does. In order to "clear" a CSS property, you must set it back to its default, which is defined by the CSS standard. Thus you should look up the defaults in your favorite reference.

```
table.other {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 0;
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
Set min-width: inherit /* Reset the min-width */
```

Try this. It will work.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. `min-width: 0` doesn't do the same thing

Comment: Right, but what if a parent has a `min-width`? you're going to get that instead of a real default.

Answer (score 7):

The default `display` property for a table is `display:table;`. The only other useful value is `inline-table`. All other `display` values are invalid for table elements.

There isn't an `auto` option to reset it to default, although if you're working in Javascript, you can set it to an empty string, which will do the trick.

`width:auto;` is valid, but isn't the default. The default width for a table is `100%`, whereas `width:auto;` will make the element only take up as much width as it needs to.

`min-width:auto;` isn't allowed. If you set `min-width`, it must have a value, but setting it to zero is probably as good as resetting it to default.

Comment: interesting idea about JS. looks like what i need.And I will try with CSS first.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `display: none;` will not display the table at all, try `display: inline-block;` with the width and min-width declarations remaining 'auto'.

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I've found to revert a min-width setting is:

```
min-width: 0;
min-width: unset;
```

unset is in the spec, but some browsers (IE 10) do not respect it, so 0 is a good fallback in *most* cases.
min-width: 0;

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Javascript to perfect everything.

My JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/QEpJH/612/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/240/300">
</div>

<h3 style="clear: both;">Full Size Image - For Reference</h3>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/240/300">
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color:#000;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;

    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    overflow:hidden;

}
```

JS:

```
$(".container").each(function(){
    var divH = $(this).height()
    var divW = $(this).width()
    var imgH = $(this).children("img").height();
    var imgW = $(this).children("img").width();

    if ( (imgW/imgH) < (divW/divH)) { 
        $(this).addClass("1");
        var newW = $(this).width();
        var newH = (newW/imgW) * imgH;
        $(this).children("img").width(newW); 
        $(this).children("img").height(newH); 
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("2");
        var newH = $(this).height();
        var newW = (newH/imgH) * imgW;
        $(this).children("img").width(newW); 
        $(this).children("img").height(newH); 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried:

```
width:0%
```

Worked for me